# More elegant way to parse inline variables in strings

Tags: php, string, parsing

Currently I have this:

```
function parse_string($string, $variables){
    extract($variables);
    return eval('return "'. addcslashes($string, '"') .'";');
}
```

So I can input this string:

```
'Hi {$name}, my name is {$own_name}'
```

Together with this array:

```
array('name' => 'John', 'own_name' => 'Tom')
```

And get this back:

```
'Hi John, my name is Tom'
```

I've never liked this `eval()` approach but it works and it's fast (faster than regex at least).

Question: Is there a more elegant way to do this (faster than using regex) in PHP5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($variables as $variable => $value) {
    $string = str_replace('{$' . $variable . '}', $value, $string);
}
```

Comment: I did some benchmarks and your solution turned out to be even faster than the one I had. Thank you.