# PHP: How to update values of variables in a string? (inline variable parsing updates)

Tags: php, string, parsing

Is there a simple way to update the values of variables that are already present in strings (without using [eval or replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460656/more-elegant-way-to-parse-inline-variables-in-strings) functions) with the `{$var}` syntax?

[In this example](http://ideone.com/HVkjn6):

```
$id_a=1; $id_b = 2;
echo $str = "The id {$id_a} is related to id {$id_b}\n";
// operations go in here that calculate new values for $id_ variables
$id_a=124214; $id_b=325325;
echo $str = "The id {$id_a} is related to id {$id_b}\n";
```

You notice that I am assigning the same string twice to `$str`.
My goal is to assign only once and every time I `echo $str` if `$id_a` or `$id_b` were changed, `$str` would have the updated values.

If there is a function that achieves this (even if it was not intended for specifically doing this), I haven't found it yet and I would be glad to know about it...

Comment: *without using eval or replace* What is wrong with replacing them? You somehow need a placeholder, which you can change out. For what else are you looking for?

Comment: @Rizier123 I gave a short example... The string I am dealing with has lots of variables, and assigning the whole string again is not an option.

Comment: Why would you need to assign it again, just assign it once with placeholder and replace them every time, before you print the string. I don't see why you can't use a placeholder, which you then can replace

Comment: Don't use a string, use a function.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is a template library.

Comment: Or maybe `printf()`.

Comment: @Rizier123 I didn't want to replace either: _Barmar_, _AbraCadaver_, _dukelukem_ and _mmm_ gave me a valid and working alternative. Thanks to all of you. It's exactly what I needed and maybe that's why there is no such function in PHP for doing this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) to specify where the arguments need to appear in the string and pass $id_a and $id_b as parameters. E.g.

```
$id_a=1; $id_b = 2;
$format = "The id %d is related to id %d\n";
echo sprintf($format, $id_a, $id_b);
// operations go in here that calculate new values for $id_ variables
$id_a=124214; $id_b=325325;
echo sprintf($format, $id_a, $id_b);
```

This way you only declare your string's structure once and can re-use where-ever you need to output it. This also has the advantage of being able to convert your arguments into various formats (check the [PHP docs](http://php.net/sprintf) page)

Comment: Well, I honestly didn't remember the `printf` option at all. Thanks dukelukem and AbraCadaver for mentioning it.

Comment: @Armfoot LOL, and you said, that you don't want to replace them... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787955/php-how-to-update-values-of-variables-in-a-string-inline-variable-parsing-upd#comment49625500_30787955 25 minutes ago already asked *why not*

Comment: @Rizier123 LOL I still don't get you Rizi... `sprintf` is reusing the `$format` variable, is that a hidden replacement happening somewhere? What about Barmar's answer? Care to detail?

Comment: @Armfoot Yep, that is what `sprintf()` or `printf()` are doing, you specify a placeholder, which you them can replace with some values. That's why I asked you right at the start, why you don't want to use replacement's.

Comment: @Rizier123 you could have written an answer with your placeholder solution, you were the first one to ask me details about it anyway... However I appreciate your generous -1 for making a point over such a serious matter. _mmm_'s and _duke_'s solutions were straight to the point and maybe they do operate in a similar way to `str_replace`, but I doubt it's heavier for the compiler and well... I won't be using a "replacement" after all ;)

Answer (score 1):

with the idea of **Barmar**, it makes that :

```
function calculateString($id_a, $id_b) {
    return "The id {$id_a} is related to id {$id_b}\n";
}

$id_a=1; $id_b = 2;
echo $str = calculateString($id_a, $id_b);
$id_a=124214; $id_b=325325;
echo $str = calculateString($id_a, $id_b);
```